# Select creating a Column with results of another query as a JSON

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a query that will fetch results from table `parties`. This table contains two foreign keys and I'm having trouble "mapping" these foreign keys.
For the first foreign key I need to map my `host_id` column to the actual name of the person `users.name`.

I was able to solve this with:

```
SELECT parties.*, users.name as host_name
FROM parties 
INNER JOIN users ON parties.host_id = users.id
```

My second foreign key is to a table called `guests` which has a FK  named `party_refer` which refers to `parties.id`.

The following query includes my Guests as part of the results (by appending all of my guests table columns in the results)

```
SELECT parties.*, users.name as host_name, guests.*
FROM parties 
INNER JOIN users ON parties.host_id = users.id
INNER JOIN guests ON parties.id = guests.party_refer
```

I would like to modify this second INNER JOIN so that the results of (`select * from guests`) are returned as a single Column called `Guests` with the results expressed as a JSON.

I believe I need to use `array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json()))` but I've been trying for hours to get it working with no luck.

Comment: Just use `json_agg(…)`, not `array_to_json(array_agg(…))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
SELECT parties.*, users.name as host_name, json_agg(row_to_json(guests)) as guests
FROM parties 
INNER JOIN users ON parties.host_id = users.id
INNER JOIN guests ON parties.id = guests.party_refer
GROUP BY parties.id, users.name
```

Although a subquery may be simpler than extensive grouping:

```
SELECT
  parties.*,
  users.name as host_name,
  (SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(guests))
    FROM guests
    WHERE guests.party_refer = parties.id) as guests
FROM parties 
INNER JOIN users ON parties.host_id = users.id
```

([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1ed921bd4e5eff271c4541d9afa04187))

You might prefer an explicit `json_build_object` instead of the `row_to_json`, e.g.

```
json_agg(json_build_object('guestName', guests.name))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think this sounds about right! Unfortunately the first query is giving me `ERROR: column "parties.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` and the second one is giving me `ERROR: function row_to_json() does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: @HowieNoble Ah, fixed. Apparently `*` is not available where I expected it to be.